# virt-manager has no option to add sata disk? [arch]

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kvm, virt-manager

I've been trying to get a windows 10 vm going for a bit now and so far I've made it to where I sucessfully boot into a windows installation, issue is however is that it requires disk drivers (virtio) for it to work, I've tried adding those drivers by putting them on a cdrom disk from virt-manager using SCSI as the bus however The windows installer ignored the disk and doesn't detect it. I dug a bit and found something in the archwiki that mentioned that the only way to do this with windows 8.1+ was to use SATA as the bus, however my virt-manager only gives me the option between IDE and SCSI and using IDE prevents me from even running the machine in the first place, any idea as to why SATA isn't showing up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why SATA disappeared from menu, but now you have to type sata (in lowercase) instead of IDE

Comment: Can you explain further your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but if you don't get the text input box on bus type on "customize virt install"'s popup, go back and instead of letting virt-manager's "New Virtual Machine" wizard create a disk automatically, use "select or create custom storage"; the bus option wont be there, but when I got back to the "customize" step at the end, I could enter 'sata' in a text box that was no longer a locked drop down